# checking if user exist in database any more every 1 hour[Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to check the user data every hour in my main.dart

I have a `Loginstate()` class and `signin` Function inside it

when I call `Loginstate().signin();` its return me null

then I tried to set  a Timer in my Login page but the problem is Timer is activate just when user go to login page and its not active in my main dart page

any advice?

Comment: So according to what I understood from ur question.
1. You should use streambuilder in order to check if user is logged in or not.
2.You can always declare your Time in main.dart in the main() function

Comment: @ Maadhav Sharma thanks for your comment.if i use the streambuilder it will refresh automaticly its important to me that login fuction refreshing data without opening login page